# Convert IP address to integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, integer, ip-address

I have a Pandas data frame, below and I am trying to convert the IP address into an integer.

```
    install Network subnet_bits Next    Hop AS1 AS2 AS3 AS4 
0   *   1.0.0.0 24.0    202.12.28.1 0   4777    13335   i   NaN NaN 
1   *   1.0.4.0 22.0    202.12.28.1 0   4777    6939    4826    38803   56203
2   *   1.0.4.0 24.0    202.12.28.1 0   4777    6939    4826    38803   56203
```

I am using the `ipaddress` library. It seems the index is getting in the way.  I can't figure out how to easily convert the UP address to an integer.

Here is my code:

```py
try:
    network = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(df['Network']))
    print(network)
except ValueError:
    print('address/netmask is invalid for IPv4:', df.Network)
```

Here is the error message:

```
address/netmask is invalid for IPv4: 

0             1.0.0.0
1             1.0.4.0
2             1.0.4.0
```

Comment: What column does the `*` belong to?

Comment: What do you expect the result of `int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(...))` to be? An IP address is four numbers, how do you want to convert it to one number?

Comment: @kaya3 IPv4 address has an unambiguous representation as a 32 bit unsigned integer. I think we can even say that this is the native format of IPv4 address! See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addressing

Comment: @pabouk Not unambiguous - it can be big-endian or little-endian. Besides, if the OP meant this then their question needs to say so, hence my request for clarification.

Comment: @kaya3 The 32-bit field as present in the IPv4 header is the native format of an IP address. The RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc790 describes the order of the bits (you can call it endianness of the 32-bit field) and also shows the translation to the most common textual notation - dotted-decimal. Besides this notation of IPv4 address there is also the dotless notation (the unsigned int 32 bit in decimal) implemented in many major networking libraries and tools. Try this: `ping 2130706433` (`2130706433 == 0x7f000001`) It is the same as `ping 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @pabouk I am not sure why you are pinging me about this - I wrote a comment requesting clarification two years ago, the question doesn't mention RFC 790, but if you feel that the question doesn't need clarification regardless then you are entitled to think so.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that `ipaddress.IPv4Address` does not support operation vector wised on a column.

Try this:

```
df['int_network'] = df['Network'].apply(lambda x: int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(x)))
```

And also, make sure in `try, catch` when debugging you print out the original error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to integer like this:

````
import socket
import struct

def ip2int(addr):
    return struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(addr))[0]

dff=io.StringIO("""ms network subnet dest unk ASN1, ASN2, ASN3, ASN4, ASN5
0 * 1.0.0.0 24.0 202.12.28.1 0 4777 13335 i NaN NaN
1 * 1.0.4.0 22.0 202.12.28.1 0 4777 6939 4826 38803 56203
2 * 1.0.4.0 24.0 202.12.28.1 0 4777 6939 4826 38803 56203""")

sub = pd.read_csv(dff, sep=' ')     

sub.network.apply(lambda x: ip2int(x)) 
#0    16777216
#1    16778240
#2    16778240
#Name: network, dtype: int64

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `clean_ip` from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_ip
df = pd.DataFrame({"Network": ["1.0.0.0", "1.0.4.0", "1.0.4.0"]})

df2 = clean_ip(df, "Network", output_format="integer")
# print(df2)
   Network  Network_clean
0  1.0.0.0       16777216
1  1.0.4.0       16778240
2  1.0.4.0       16778240
```